# Can a Smarty PHP site run on Azure Web Apps

Tags: php, azure

I'm new to the Smarty templating engine but have been given a site to modify. I have it working locally on a Linux Mint box. I want to put it on Azure Web Apps (not a VM) temporarily to show the client.  I have successfully created an Azure Web App running PHP 5.4, uploaded the site files, created a MySQL DB and imported the data successfully. I've also modified the DB connection info and server host name details in the Smarty core files.  However, when I hit the xxx.azurewebsites.com url I just get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."  I set the _core/cache properties to 7xx using FileZilla and still get the same.

I'm not even sure if Smarty will even run on Azure web apps.

Any advice to get this working would be appreciated.

Thnx.

Comment: Smarty shouldn't make a difference in this case, it's just a library that uses standard PHP features.

Comment: Thank you. I read the installation docs and got the impression it might have been something deeper as I haven't "installed" Smarty, just copied the site files over. I'll look into the Azure side of it now, the hard part! lol

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can - I've just spun up (and subsequently killed off) an instance of smarty to prove this on one of my environments.

As another user said in the comments, smarty is a series of libraries which in turn leverage standard php functionality.

When deploying, remember to set a PHP version compatible with whichever version of smarty you are running and you should be good to go.

Configuring PHP version in Azure App Service: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux

(snippet for clarity):

```
az webapp config set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --linux-fx-version "PHP|8.0"
```

Smarty Documentation (for version info):
https://www.smarty.net/documentation

Hope this helps.